# 'rostopic' and other commands fail after upgrade

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got an issue after upgrading my machines where I can't run rostopic or other key ros commands.

I foolishly ran 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade' on both robots and my workstation without checking upgrading didn't break anything, and they're all displaying the same behavior, so I'm certain it's not my config.

Here's what I get when I try and run 'rostopic':

```
turtlebot@turtleVM:~$ rostopic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/rostopic", line 34, in <module>
    import rostopic
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 59, in <module>
    import rospy.impl.init
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/init.py", line 107, in <module>
    class RosStreamHandler(rosgraph.roslogging.RosStreamHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RosStreamHandler'
```

My .bashrc doesn't have anything super special in it, here's the end:

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
. /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/setup_kobuki.sh
export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=asus_xtion_pro
export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://bert:11311"
```

Some other enviornment variables that might be relevant:
ROS_DISTRO is 'groovy'
PYTHONPATH is /opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
$PYTHON_CODE_BUILD_ROS_PACKAGE_PATH  is set to 'from **future** import print_function import os env_name = 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH' paths = [path for path in os.environ[env_name].split(os.pathsep)] if env_name in os.environ and os.environ[env_name] != '' else [] workspaces = [path for path in paths if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, '.catkin'))] paths = [] for workspace in workspaces: filename = os.path.join(workspace, '.catkin') data = '' with open(filename) as f: data = f.read() if data == '': paths.append(os.path.join(workspace, 'share')) paths.append(os.path.join(workspace, 'stacks')) else: for source_path in data.split(';'): paths.append(source_path) print(os.pathsep.join(paths))'

Don't know where that last one came from, but it looks like it's something quite deliberate.

My default python is 2.7.3, and if I run it and type 'import ros' it finds the package.

Any ideas what to check or how to get my system working again?

Thanks,
Gavin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59644/%27rostopic%27-and-other-commands-fail-after-upgrade/) by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 478 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-31**:
What happens when you get rid of the source of setup_kobuki.sh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this same problem and it turns out that apt-get was holding back an update to the ros-groovy-rosgraph package.

Check the packages that are held back by running $sudo apt-get upgrade, and if it is held back, $sudo aptitude safe-upgrade --full-resolver, should force it to install.

---

Originally posted by [awilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4577/awilson/) with karma: 231 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-04-02**:
Thanks! Held back packages seem to be the problem. My system didn't have aptitude on there, but running 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' solved it, and I believe turtlebot-dashboard was holding stuff back.

For others, note: 'dist-upgrade' is a dangerous command, so check man pages before running it.

**Comment by [jetdillo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4081/jetdillo/) on 2013-04-21**:
Indeed, 'apt-get dist upgrade' should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into this as well and fixed it by looking at the list of held-back packages:

```
The following packages have been kept back:

  ros-groovy-actionlib ros-groovy-common-msgs ros-groovy-geometry
  ros-groovy-nodelet-core ros-groovy-pluginlib ros-groovy-ros
  ros-groovy-ros-comm ros-groovy-ros-tutorials ros-groovy-rosgraph
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
ubuntu@arm:~/catkin_ws$
```

I did a manual 'apt-get install ros-groovy-actionlib', which succeeded.
That apparently released all the others except ros-groovy-rosgraph, because now `apt-get upgrade` reported:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  ros-groovy-rosgraph
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ros-groovy-common-msgs ros-groovy-geometry ros-groovy-nodelet-core
  ros-groovy-pluginlib ros-groovy-ros ros-groovy-ros-comm
  ros-groovy-ros-tutorials
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 42.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 66.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
```

Now I could `apt-get install ros-groovy-rosgraph` to finish the job.
I was able to get roscore running successfully after this.

So there are a couple points here I guess:

1. I was able to get my Groovy install to a point where it could run roscore using the above procedure.
2. I didn't have to do a 'dist-upgrade' to get this all working.
3. Fixing install order dependencies for individual packages (if they occur) is preferable to breaking your whole OS install if a dist-upgrade goes bad for some reason.

---

Originally posted by [jetdillo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4081/jetdillo/) with karma: 41 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3